# Difference between scipy.leastsq and scipy.least_squares

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, least-squares

I was wondering what the difference between the two methods [`scipy.optimize.leastsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) and [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) is?

When I implement them they yield minimal differences in chi^2:

```
>>> solution0 = ((p0.fun).reshape(100,100))
>>> # p0.fun are the residuals of my fit function np.ravel'ed as returned by least_squares
>>> print(np.sum(np.square(solution0))) 
0.542899505806

>>> solution1 = np.square((median-solution1))
>>> # solution1 is the solution found by least_sq, it does not yield residuals thus I have to subtract it from the median to get the residuals (my special case)
>>> print(np.sum((solution1)))
0.54402852325
```

Could anybody expand on that or point out where I can find an alternative documentation, the one from scipy is a bit cryptic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs for `least_squares`, it would appear that `leastsq` is an older wrapper.

> **See also**
>
> [leastsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#scipy.optimize.leastsq)   A legacy wrapper for the MINPACK implementation of the Levenberg-Marquadt algorithm.

So you should just use `least_squares`. It appears that `least_squares` has additional functionality. Foremost among them is that the default "method" (i.e. algorithm) used is different:

> - `trf` : Trust Region Reflective algorithm, particularly suitable for large sparse problems with bounds. Generally robust method.
> - `dogbox` : dogleg algorithm with rectangular trust regions, typical use case is small problems with bounds. Not recommended for problems
>     with rank-deficient Jacobian.
> - `lm` : Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm as implemented in MINPACK. Doesn’t handle bounds and sparse Jacobians. Usually the most efficient
>     method for small unconstrained problems.
>
> Default is `trf`. See Notes for more information.

The old `leastsq` algorithm was only a wrapper for the `lm` method, which—as the docs say—is good only for small unconstrained problems.

The difference you see in your results might be due to the difference in the algorithms being employed.

Answer (score 4):

The **key reason** for writing the new Scipy function [least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) is to allow for upper and lower bounds on the variables (also called "box constraints"). This was a highly requested feature.

This apparently simple addition is actually far from trivial and required completely new algorithms, specifically the dogleg (`method="dogleg"` in `least_squares`) and the trust-region reflective (`method="trf"`), which allow for a robust and efficient treatment of box constraints (details on the algorithms are given in the references to the relevant Scipy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) ).

Also important is the support for large-scale problems and sparse Jacobians.

When bounds on the variables are not needed, and the problem is not very large, the algorithms in the new Scipy function `least_squares` have little, if any, advantage with respect to the Levenberg-Marquardt MINPACK implementation used in the old `leastsq` one.

However, the very same MINPACK Fortran code is called both by the old `leastsq` and by the new `least_squares` with the option `method="lm"`. For this reason, the old `leastsq` is now obsoleted and is not recommended for new code.

Comment: Is it possible to provide different bounds on the variables. My problem requires the first half of the variables to be positive and the second half to be in [0,1]. It is hard to make this fix?

Comment: Of course, every variable has its own bound: `bounds=[(L1, L2,...), (U1, U2,...)]`

Answer (score 2):

In `least_squares` you can give upper and lower boundaries for each variable

There are some more features that leastsq does not provide if you compare the docstrings